# I use simulator it didn't crash,but when app store tested my app it crashed.(iOS 6)

Tags: xcode, ios6

They said "When the user selects the last button on the main menu on both iPhone 4 and iPad (3rd gen) running iOS 6.0, the app crashes."

Of course I tested,but everything OK.
The following code have wrong?

```
NSDictionary *soundSetting;
soundSetting = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],AVSampleRateKey,
                [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC],AVFormatIDKey,
                [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2],AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityHigh],
                AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,nil];

NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES)objectAtIndex: 0];
//Spades
soundFileURLSpades = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[docDir
                                                    stringByAppendingString:     @"soundSpades.caf"]];
self.audioRecorderSpades = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                      initWithURL: soundFileURLSpades
                      settings: soundSetting
                      error: nil];
```

Comment: You always need to test on a device before submitting. The simulator is not an emulator. If possible, it's best to test on every device and OS version you're going to support, but it's critical to test on at least a single device.

Comment: I have tested on iPhone with iOS5,everything all right.Did record audio have difference betweent iOS5 and iOS6?